# Find Value from multiple workbooks and copy found rows with format (color) into new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet

I have workbooks for each month. They all contain rows with date, tramline number and a delay reason. To specify the delay reason the row with the entry is color-coded red or green. To search for specific tramline number and date across the workbooks i used the code below. It's perfect. But the result however comes back in a new sheet without the color code.
 I tried to change the application.transpose command and had a look at the ws.cells.find command together with a IT pro from my company. But no one knows VBA.
 Please help.
 Thanks for your help

```
Sub SearchWB()
Dim myDir As String, fn As String, ws As Worksheet, r As Range
Dim a(), n As Long, x As Long, myTask As String, ff As String, temp
myDir = "V:\Test\" '<- change path to folder with files to search
If Dir(myDir, 16) = "" Then
    MsgBox "No such folder path", 64, myDir
    Exit Sub
End If
myTask = InputBox("Suckkriterium:")
If myTask = "" Then Exit Sub
x = Columns.Count
fn = Dir(myDir & "*.*")
    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With
Do While fn <> ""
    With Workbooks.Open(myDir & fn, 0)
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            Set r = ws.Cells.Find(myTask, , , 1)
            If Not r Is Nothing Then
                ff = r.Address
                Do
                    n = n + 1
                    temp = r.EntireRow.Value
                    ReDim Preserve temp(1 To 1, 1 To x)
                    ReDim Preserve a(1 To n)
                    a(n) = temp
                    Set r = ws.Cells.FindNext(r)
                Loop While ff <> r.Address
            End If
        Next
        .Close False
    End With
    fn = Dir
Loop
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eintrag SUCHEN").Rows(1)
    .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
    If n > 0 Then
        .Resize(n).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(a))
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found", , myTask
    End If
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Könnten Sie das vielleicht auf Englisch übersetzen?

Comment: Con un par!!! Y si cuela, cuela!!! Joer macho, si cada uno ponemos un idioma, esto va a ser la juerga padre xD

Comment: @Color Code Du brauchst ein `)` mit `InputBox` für `MyTask` no??Repariere diese Linie bitte :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is in German on a strictly English site.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT as per user comment:

This way you copy only values. Try this for copying values and formats:

```
Do
    n = n + 1
    Range(ws.Cells(r.Row, 1), ws.Cells(r.Row, x)).Copy
    Set rDst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eintrag SUCHEN").Cells(1, n)
    rDst.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    Set r = ws.Cells.FindNext(r)
Loop ...
```

This way you eliminate using temp and a() and `Redim Preserve`.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion. 
" temp = r.EntireRow.Copy"
clashes with "ReDim Preserve temp(1 To 1, 1 To x)". 
Could you try again please?
Thanks a lot
Lars

Comment: With this he says: invalid Proceedure or invalid argument, pointing to: .Resize(n).Value = _
            Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(a))
Then I took out (Application.Transpose(a)) and he came back with "invalid amount of arguments"

Comment: This error message is correct because you don't assing a value to a. However, if you apply my version, you can completely omit the next block (`With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eintrag ... End With`) as the values have already been copypasted within the loop. Try to run it in Debug mode step by step and see what happens.

Comment: Wow thanks so much. I placed it now correctly and it gives me the answer I want. But the outcome should be in a row. It is now in a column. And I have to acknowledge the pop up question to keep the data in memory.
Can that be solved? Thanks so much for your help!!!

Comment: Oh I see. You double transposed the range in the original source. So amend my code with this: `Set rDst = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Eintrag SUCHEN").Cells(n, 1)` and `rDst.PasteSpecial Transpose:=False` and put `Application.CutCopyMode = False` next to `Loop` command (so it executes only once)

Comment: WOW. now it is working perfectly. One more question please. If I want to take out the loop that opens the next workbook so that I only search in one workbook. I implanted the following at the beginning SaveDriveDir = CurDir
       ChDrive "V:"
    ChDir "V:\Test"
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
MultiSelect:=True)
That opens a workbook of my choice, but it still runs through all other workbooks in that folder anyway.
Thanks a million!!!!

Comment: `Do While fn <> ""` and `Loop` makes the loop. Remove these lines and the code between them will execute only once.

Comment: Thanks for that. The code opens my chosen workbook `code:
SaveDriveDir = CurDir
ChDrive "V:"
ChDir "V:\Test\"
fn = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
MultiSelect:=True)
If Not IsArray(fn) Then Exit Sub`
But further down it opens the workbook with: `code:
With Workbooks.Open(myDir & fn, 0)
For Each ws In .Worksheets
Set r = ws.Range("C:C").Find(myTask, , , 1)
If Not r Is Nothing Then
ff = r.Address`